# Random walk with a boundary condition in python 3

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to write a 2D random walk with random step lenght and random angle. The random walk should work like this: starting from $(0, 0)$ a random angle between $0$ and $\pi$ is generated and new coordinates $(x=rsin(\theta), y=rcos(\theta)$ are generated. $r$ is choosen in a random way as $r=step_size*(random.uniform(0, 1))$ with $step_size = .1$. The boundary conditions are that, when the walker passes from the left of the plot to the right, the new step is increased on $x$ and on $y$ by $.6$ and then the step lenght become again random as before. The code then check that $x$ and $y$ are not over the plot boundaries. [image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import random
import time
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


n = 100000
x, y, theta = np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n)
xp, yp = np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n)
start_time = time.time()
step_size = .1

for i in range(1, n):
    theta[i] = theta[i-1] + random.uniform(0, 1)*2*math.pi
    xp[i] = xp[i-1] + step_size*(random.uniform(0, 1))*math.sin(theta[i])
    yp[i] = yp[i-1] + step_size*(random.uniform(0, 1))*math.cos(theta[i])
    if xp[i] >= 0  and xp[i-1] < 0: #if the next point will be within the box and the previous point was outside the box
        x[i] = xp[i] + .6
        y[i] = yp[i] + .6
    else: 
        x[i] = xp[i]
        y[i] = yp[i]
    if x[i] > 10 or x[i] < -10:
            x[i] = x[i-1]
    if y[i] > 10 or y[i] < -10:
            y[i] = y[i-1]
```

x[p] and y[p] are used to see whether the next point will be within x>0, if so I increase x and y by .6.
**The problem is that**, as you can see from the image, everytime the walker crosses the boundary it does two steps with a lenght increased of $.6$ instead than only one and it does that sort of scissor you see on the boundary. The boundary is the red line in the center.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the context, but shouldn't it be `xp[i] = x[i-1] + step_si...` ? what do you actually want to happen whenever the walker crosses the boundary ?

Comment: @Swifty Sorry if I only reply now. Thanks but the problem was another; however, I was able to solve it.